# Trying to build React-Admin, keeps getting "Edit src/App.js and save to reload"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I am very new to React, so please bare with me :/

Currently I am trying to build React-Admin, so I did as instructed:

```
yarn create react-app test-admin
cd test-admin/
yarn add react-admin ra-data-json-server prop-types
yarn start
```

I added "homepage: ".", to the package.json as well;

Next I entered "yarn build".

I have tried every possible way to fix this, but I keep getting the message "Edit src/App.js and save to reload." (on http://store-masters.com/test-admin/build/);

What am I missing here?

Comment: It's as simple as following the instructions: Edit `src/App.js` and save to reload. Open that file in your editor (open the `src` folder of `test-admin` and edit the file called `App.js`) and make some changes! When you save, the app will automatically show your changes. Unless I misunderstood the question, there is no problem.

Answer (score -1):

It's not an error message, it's the home page (in your file src/App.js) of your app react, you can find this sentence in your file App.js (if there is a component or a page, look at it!) If you only have this sentence 'Edit src/App.js and save to reload.' it's probably because you removed the logo of react, so only the sentence left, but it's not an error! So you can continue to develop

Answer (score -1):

In Visual Studio, Click the save button at the top, go back to the react website and reload the page. That should fix it.

Comment: Please only post answers that are pertinent to the question. This question doesn't specify any specific editor, because the editor doesn't matter. In the future, try to address the question instead of saying how *you* solved the question.

Answer (score -2):

try to write in your terminal:
npm install

Comment: Why will this solve the issue?

Comment: Because the reload page, ("Edit Src/App ..." ) it's not an error and I think that maybe it can work because to run React you need to use NodeJs and to be able to use it you need to have the neccesary packages for NodeJs that has npm.  In that case I wouldn't use Yarn to run the application, if not  npm start... But I'm not one hundred percent sure. But in my case it works

Comment: Sure, but making sure you have all your necessary packages installed is just general programming advice, not a specific solution to this specific question on its own